# How to add name to the DatePickerSingle in Dash/Plotly

Tags: python, plotly-dash

How do I add label above my DatePickerSingle and Dropdowns?
Scenario is similar to question posted [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63802599/how-to-name-to-the-dropdown-menu-in-dash-plotly) just replacing Slider wit

```
import dash
```

import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(**name**, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div(

```
html.Div(className='row', children=[
    
    html.Div(children=[
            html.Label(['Dataset:'], style={'font-weight': 'bold', "text-align": "center"}),
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='dropdown-dataset',
                options=[
                    {'label': 'Diabetes', 'value': 'diabetes'},
                    {'label': 'Boston Housing', 'value': 'boston'},
                    {'label': 'Sine Curve', 'value': 'sin'}

                ],
                value='diabetes',
                searchable=False,
                clearable=False,
            ),
            html.Label('DatePicker', style={'font-weight': 'bold', "text-align": "center"}),
            dcc.DatePickerSingle(
                                 calendar_orientation='vertical',
                                 placeholder='Select a date',
                                 date=date(2017, 6, 21)
                                 ),

        ], style=dict(width='33.33%')),

    
    html.Div(children=[
            html.Label(['Model Type'], style={'font-weight': 'bold', "text-align": "center"}),
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='dropdown-select-model',
                options=[
                    {'label': 'Linear Regression', 'value': 'linear'},
                    {'label': 'Lasso', 'value': 'lasso'},
                    {'label': 'Ridge', 'value': 'ridge'},
                    {'label': 'Polynomial', 'value': 'polynomial'},
                    {'label': 'elastic-net', 'value': 'elastic-net'},

                ],
                value='linear',
                searchable=False,
                clearable=False
            ),
            html.Label('Slider', style={'font-weight': 'bold', "text-align": "center"}),
            dcc.Slider(
                min=0,
                max=9,
                marks={i: 'Label {}'.format(i) if i == 1 else str(i) for i in range(1, 6)},
                value=5,
            ),
        ],style=dict(width='33.33%')),

    html.Div(children=[
            html.Label(['Add data'], style={'font-weight': 'bold', "text-align": "center"}),
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='dropdown-custom-selection',
                options=[
                    {'label': 'Add Training Data', 'value': 'training'},
                    {'label': 'Add Test Data', 'value': 'test'},
                    {'label': 'Remove Data point', 'value': 'remove'},
                ],
                value='training',
                clearable=False,
                searchable=False
            ),
            html.Label('Slider', style={'font-weight': 'bold', "text-align": "center"}),
            dcc.Slider(
                min=0,
                max=9,
                marks={i: 'Label {}'.format(i) if i == 1 else str(i) for i in range(1, 6)},
                value=5,
            ),
        ],style=dict(width='33.33%')),
],style=dict(display='flex')),
```

)

if **name** == '**main**':
app.run_server(debug=True, port=8080)

Comment: You might want to have a look at https://dash-mantine-components.herokuapp.com/components/datepicker. I'm the author of this library and this documentations is a work in progress but you can reach out to me if you want any help.